# How to modify text in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I made a script to retrieve data from an API and show it in HTML.
The problem is that the API answers with something like that

```plaintext
[{"seen":"2021-08-24 04:13:51"}]
```

And I want the user to see something like

```plaintext
2021-08-24 04:13:51
```

How can i modify this text inside of javascript? (The output is variable but the number of characters is always the same, idk if this is a useful info...)

Comment: you need to put a bit more effort into how to access array and obj. And pls post your questions adding what you tried, where are you stuck. No one will write the code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is returning data in json format, you need to parse the response to a javascript object and then you can use the value as you want

```js
const theServerResponse = '[{"seen":"2021-08-24 04:13:51"}]'

const parsedResponse = JSON.parse(theServerResponse)


//At this point you can get that value
parsedResponse[0].seen
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is set `innerText` value from the JSON. You can access the value using `response[0].seen`

```js
const response = [{"seen":"2021-08-24 04:13:51"}];
console.log(response[0].seen);
document.getElementById('lastupdatedon').innerText = response[0].seen;
```

```html
<p id="lastupdatedon"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below script

```
                var fromAPI='[{"seen":"2021-08-24 04:13:51"}]';
                var data=JSON.parse(fromAPI);
                if(data!=null && data.length>0)
                {
                    document.getElementById('lastupdatedon').innerText = data[0].seen;
                }
```

HTML

```
<h3 id="lastupdatedon"></h3>
```

Do not forget to check for nulls, index is greater than 0. IF server doesnt return data then your app will throw an error of undefined.